# If a liquid and a solid are at the same temperature, do they have the same kinetic energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, states-of-matter

If you have two different materials at the same temperature but are at different states of matter, do they have the same amount of kinetic energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you mean a solid and liquid of different (has to be different) materials.

Temperature is a measure proportional to the average kinetic energy of each particle. So if we keep the number of moles (molecules) the same in the solid and liquid in question, then theoretically yes.

But we can't ignore the chemical properties of the substances (interactions between molecules) if we're to be realistic. I'm guessing that in most solids kinetic energy is transferred by electrons more than anything. In metals the atoms also vibrate but what can we say about the storage of heat energy in a macromolecular structure like silicon dioxide? It's an interesting question but all I can say is that it is true for ideal gases of any kind. That is, if two samples of ideal gases are taken with the same number of moles, they both have the same energy. I cannot answer you're question for liquids and solids, but there is probably no simple description of how it works.

Comment: At the melting point, the solid and liquid are quite happy to coexist in thermodynamic equilibrium. So, no, they can be the same material.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I want to know if the molecules in both the liquid and the solid are vibrating at the same speed.

Comment: Yeah I missed that. But again it's an effect due to intermolecular forced

Comment: Well then yes they will be different by M/m = v^2/V^2. Where m and M is molar mass. But of course this is making gross assumptions like that the energy is only carried by particles of one mass in the substance. But in metals electrons and ions carry this energy for example.

Comment: And if we take Jon Custer s example, imagine a liquid that when frozen can only have it's atoms oscillate in one dimension. Well then the ratio of the velocity of liquid over solid squares v^2/V^2 = 2/3. We can apply the equipartition theorem to simple situations like this

Comment: Sorry I haven't really learned the math yet, I'm only 14 so I haven't learned those formulas yet. So both the substances' particles are moving at the same speed but the liquid's particles are just moving more freely?

Comment: yep, pretty much. But remember this is inapplicable to most solids and liquids because energy is not transferred the way we would assume it is in classical mechanics when the distance between atoms is small

Comment: It's interesting that an answer containing the phrase "I cannot answer you're [sic] question for liquids and solids"  is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Within a regime where the [equipartition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem) provides a good description of the kinetic degrees of freedom in a material (generally this will mean at relatively high temperatures) each atom will have a mean kinetic energy of $\frac{3}{2}k_BT$, regardless of the state of matter. More generally, however, you would not expect there to be a general relationship between the kinetic energy and temperature. In particular in a solid at at low temperatures, where it is necessary to take account of the quatisation of atomic energy levels, the equipartition theorem will not hold.